# Get maximum number in Crystal Reports?

Tags: winforms, crystal-reports

The data source passed to a report has a `Serial`  property, I need to write a field in this format for every details section: [Serial] from [Top serial]
I wrote this formula for the top serial:

```
Maximum({VW_Sizes.Serial})
```

but it gets the current serial, so instead of 1 of 2, 2 of 2

it gets 1 of 1, 2 of 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are running into is that when each iteration of the details section prints to the report, it only knows the Max value for SERIAL for the rows that have already printed to the report.

I prefer to use a SQL Expression Field to get around this issue.  This allows you to use a SQL query to retrieve the maximum value of SERIAL for the grouped data before all of the rows are printed to the report.

Something like this usually works for me.

```
(
SELECT MAX("ORD_DETAIL"."ORD_DET_SEQNO") 
FROM ORD_DETAIL 
WHERE "ORD_DETAIL"."ORDERS_ID" = "ORDERS"."ID"
)
```

In my example, I have two tables, `ORDERS` and `ORD_DETAIL`.  `ORD_DETAIL.ORD_DET_SEQNO` contains the sequence numbers of order detail rows.  My data is grouped on `ORDERS.ID` to iterate through each Order and the following formula field would print an output for each detail line that indicates its sequence out of the maximum value of all sequence numbers for that order.

```
ToText({ORD_DETAIL.ORD_DET_SEQNO}) + " of " + ToText({%Max});
```

In this formula, `%Max` is the name of the SQL Expression Field in the example above.

If you have no point in your data where the SERIAL number resets, then your SQL Expression Field would look like this.

```
(
SELECT MAX(Serial)
FROM VW_Sizes
)
```

If you need a reset at certain points, simply add a WHERE clause that references the table.column that is used to group a set of SERIAL values.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate that variable in a *Formula Field* inside your detail section with a content about this:

```
{VW_Sizes.Serial} & " from " & Maximum ({VW_Sizes.Serial})
```

otherwise you only can put a summary field with the maximum value outside the detail section, for example in *Grand Total (Report Footer)*.

Answer (score -1):

i think there is an easier way to do something like that, from the report you need to create running field from the field explorer :

- set field name e.g. (max_Serial)
- select your field to summarize.
- after selecting your field crystal report provides multiple types of summary according to field data type.
- select maximum and reset according to your requirement e.g. after each group.

Comment: This only works in footer sections that follow the details section though.  Within the details section the running total field is still not aware of a max value that may come in a details section that has not printed yet.

Comment: insert it into footer suppress it and re-call it in a new parameter field